# How to use javascript variable in smarty section loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

I have a table with id = 2 and I want to loop over it

I don't know the syntax , couldn't find anything similar on the net
please help :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var u=$('#2').find('tbody > tr').size();
<%section name='i' start=0 loop=u%>
  alert('in loop');
  <%/section%>
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot, smarty works **before** (on the server) javascript is executed (on the client)

Comment: With smarty output the entire data you have, to the DOM, with display:none. Then when the JavaScript runs, you can manipulate and show/whatever the parts you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should look in your generated source to see that the browser (client) just gets HTML and no smarty (server). What you should do is use JavaScript to write your loop and then do everything client side.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var u = $('#2 tbody > tr').each(function() {
    alert('in loop');
});
</script>
```

By the way, "2" is not a correct ID, it should always start with a letter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this entirely on client side. You need to differentiate on the code running your server, and running on your client, that is the browser.

When you want to manipulate a HTML table exists entirely inside browser, the client, you use client side code to work with it, that is Browser's language "JavaScript" which is fully capable of handling a loop by it's own. No need to use Smarty there.

You should invest sometime to learn the basics of JavaSciript.

I'll give you http://www.w3schools.com/js/ as a starting point, please do not consider this as an excellent place to learn everything about JavaScript but to get around basics it should be okay.

As per the looping example, I believe existing answer gives you a correct picture, except that it assigns the return value from `each` which I think you should remove, for easier understanding. However, having it will do no harm to you also.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#2').find('tbody > tr').each(function() {
      alert('in loop');
      // You can access the current 'tr' element using $(this)

   });
</script>
```